# Trying to convert this Mockito test to Mockk results in error

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

Having issues with the following conversion from Mockito to Mockk.

So I have this

```
@Mock
private lateinit var loginLiveDataObserver: Observer<LoginResult>

val inOrder = inOrder(loginLiveDataObserver)

inOrder.verify(loginLiveDataObserver).onChanged(enableLoading)
inOrder.verify(loginLiveDataObserver).onChanged(loginResults)
inOrder.verify(loginLiveDataObserver).onChanged(disableLoading)
```

Try turning it into this

```
private val loginLiveDataObserver = mockk<Observer<LoginResult>>()

verifyOrder {
    loginLiveDataObserver.onChanged(enableLoading)
    loginLiveDataObserver.onChanged(loginResults)
    loginLiveDataObserver.onChanged(disableLoading)
}
```

Gives me the following error

io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: Observer(#4).onChanged(Loading(value=true))

Comment: Isn't that because of the difference in sticktness? In mockk you need to specify all the behaviour.

Comment: ok hmm I could see that but then I am at a loss the `private val enableLoading = LoginResult.Loading(true)` is a sealed class

`sealed class LoginResult {

    data class Success(val user: CurrentUserResponse) : LoginResult()
    data class Loading(val value: Boolean): LoginResult()
    data class Failure(val reason: String): LoginResult()
}
`

So how do I go about mockking the results I tried this...
coEvery { LoginResult.Loading(true) } returns LoginResult.Loading(true)

but It still came back with the same error.

Comment: Also I dont know what the alternative in mockk is for this
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
I tried
@RunWith(MockKJUnitRunner::class)
But I cant get it to be found

Comment: You can try relaxed mocks (check docs) if you don't want strickness. It is hard to understand from comment what code do you have. Submit github issue with proper formatting and I'll try to help. Also check this article for advanced cases https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/mocking-is-not-rocket-science-mockk-advanced-features-42277e5983b5

Comment: No alternative for run with because it is not needed. Although you can use JUnit 5 extensions if you want (check corresponding doc section)

Comment: Oh haha duh... yeah adding the relaxed = true helped make it work :) thanks.  As always you are amazing. :)

Comment: @Crash1hd . Have you find a solution without using `relaxed = true` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your exception says it all (and one of the direct answers), you always have to specify the behaviour of your mocks..

in your case:

```
private val loginLiveDataObserver = mockk<Observer<LoginResult>>()

// Example answer you can use different here
every { loginLiveDataObserver.onChange(any()) } answers nothing

verifyOrder {
    loginLiveDataObserver.onChanged(enableLoading)
    loginLiveDataObserver.onChanged(loginResults)
    loginLiveDataObserver.onChanged(disableLoading)
}
```

Check the [Documentation](https://mockk.io/#verification-order) at this point and look for the `every { ... }` part in the example

hope this helps.

Comment: can you explain more about `answers nothing` ?

Comment: @GiovankaBisano find the docu here http://mockk.io/#answers, it says: `specify that the matched call answers null`